# Swift - UIActivityController Constraints error on iOS15.4

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I'm trying to show a `UIActivityViewController` in my application. It works well on the iPhone but I have a couple of issues with constraints:

```
2022-03-17 20:49:29.744955+0100 Instagrid[50308:1307722] [LayoutConstraints] Changing the translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints property of a UICollectionReusableView that is managed by a UICollectionView is not supported, and will result in incorrect self-sizing. View: <_UIActivityContentFooterView: 0x1206246f0; baseClass = UICollectionReusableView; frame = (20 506; 374 52); layer = <CALayer: 0x600001e7a400>>
2022-03-17 20:49:29.748855+0100 Instagrid[50308:1307722] [default] -imageForImageDescriptor: can do IO please adopt -imageForDescriptor: for IO free drawing or -prepareImageForDescriptor: if IO is allowed. (This will become a fault soon.)
2022-03-17 20:49:29.763300+0100 Instagrid[50308:1307722] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003d48280 _UIActivityActionCellTitleLabel:0x12062edd0.height >= 22   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003d0b0c0 UIView:0x12062def0.height >= _UIActivityActionCellTitleLabel:0x12062edd0.height + 30   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003d39540 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UIView:0x12062def0.height == 30   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003d48280 _UIActivityActionCellTitleLabel:0x12062edd0.height >= 22   (active)>
```

Weirdly, this issue appears only on iOS 15. When I try my code on iOS 14 and iOS 13, I don't receive this error.

Does anyone have any tips/actions to solve this issue?

---

**EDIT 1 - Code that trigger the UIActivityViewController**

```
let imageToShare = pictureView.renderAsUIImage()
let sharingObject = [imageToShare]
let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: sharingObject, applicationActivities: nil)
present(activityViewController, animated: true)

func renderAsUIImage() -> UIImage {
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: self.bounds.size)
        return renderer.image { context in
            self.drawHierarchy(in: self.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        }
}
```

Comment: Could you show the code that constructs and displays the UIActivityViewController?

Comment: Likely you can't do anything about this warning given that the layout of the `UIActivityViewController` is managed completely by iOS. I have seen similar constraint errors with iOS UI elements like this and action sheets before. Is this causing a specific problem?

Comment: Ok thank you @shim for the information. It doesn't cause any problems. Everything works well.

Comment: @matt, I edited the post to add the code that constructs and display the controller

Comment: Cool, I agree with shim, this doesn't seem to be your issue, you should just ignore the warning.

Comment: OK thank you both of you for the info. I'll then ignore it